# create new arraylist from existing arraylistt

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

I have a nested data from API. I need only some values and objects from that array list.

So, I'm trying to new simple array list but I couldn't handle with array in it.

I'll explain with sample:

```
const dummyData = [
    {
        orderDate: '20220501',
        orderNumber: '12345',
        id: '1',
        name: 'Customer 1',
        lines: [
            { id: 1, product: 'PRD001', qty: 1},
            { id: 2, product: 'PRD002', qty: 3},
        ]
    },
    {
        orderDate: '20220501',
        orderNumber: '12346',
        id: '2',
        name: 'Customer 2',
        lines: [
            { id: 1, product: 'PRD001', qty: 1 },
            { id: 2, product: 'PRD002', qty: 2 },
            { id: 3, product: 'PRD003', qty: 7 },
            { id: 4, product: 'PRD004', qty: 1 },
        ]
    },
    {
        orderDate: '20220502',
        orderNumber: '12347',
        id: '3',
        name: 'Customer 3',
        lines: [
            { id: 1, product: 'PRD001', qty: 1 },
            { id: 2, product: 'PRD002', qty: 1 },
            { id: 3, product: 'PRD003', qty: 3 },
        ]
    },
]


    const currentData = data.map(order => (
      {
        orderDate: order.orderDate,
        orderNumber: order.orderNumber,
          lines: 
            order["lines"].map(line => ({
              product: line.product,
              qty: line.qty,
            }))       
      }
    ))
    console.log("order", currentData)
```

The output is:

```
[{"lines": [[Object], [Object]], "orderDate": "20220501", "orderNumber": "12345"}, {"lines": [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]], "orderDate": "20220501", "orderNumber": "12346"}, {"lines": [[Object], [Object], [Object]], "orderDate": "20220502", "orderNumber": "12347"}]

But I'm trying to create a new array list like this:

    [{
    "lines": [
    { product: 'PRD001', qty: 1
    },
    { product: 'PRD002', qty: 3
    },     
    ],
    "orderDate": "20220501",
    "orderNumber": "12345"
}]
```

What i'm trying to do:

```
[
    {
        orderDate: '20220501',
        orderNumber: '12345',
        lines: [
            { id: 1, product: 'PRD001', qty: 1},
            { id: 2, product: 'PRD002', qty: 3},
        ]
    },
    {
        orderDate: '20220501',
        orderNumber: '12346',
        lines: [
            { product: 'PRD001', qty: 1 },
            { product: 'PRD002', qty: 2 },
            { product: 'PRD003', qty: 7 },
            { product: 'PRD004', qty: 1 },
        ]
    },
    {
        orderDate: '20220502',
        orderNumber: '12347',
        lines: [
            { product: 'PRD001', qty: 1 },
            { product: 'PRD002', qty: 1 },
            { product: 'PRD003', qty: 3 },
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Where/what environment are you using to view your output? What does logging `currentData[0].lines` show?

Comment: Can you also clarify your issue? Is the issue that you're seeing `[Object]` or is your issue that you only want one object in your output array?

Comment: Hi Nick! Thanks your reply.

The problem is I'm seeing "lines" as [Object].
I want to create "Lines" as array with objects only has product and qty.

Loggin on the Terminal VS Code

Comment: Did you try logging `currentData[0].lines`? The nodejs console only logs objects certain levels deep, after 2 levels it start logging `[Object]`.

Comment: There used to be a good page on the nodejs website that explained this. It seems that it's gone now (maybe they'll bring it back), but for now here is a link to an archived version of [that](https://web.archive.org/web/20220318113656/https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-log-an-object-in-nodejs) (I'm assuming you're using nodejs as that's what you're seeing this issue).

Comment: You're right Nick,  `currentData[0].lines`  it works.
Probably it's about loggin issue like you said. Thanks a lot.